# Are there alternative methods to "_" for subscripting in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I'm currently writing some blog content on Ghost, which uses Markdown similar to the SE Network. Unfortunately however, when attempting to subscript in math mode *i.e.* $3_{x}$, the underscore is interpreted by Markdown as italicizing text, and prevents my math from showing up correctly.

Having already filed a support ticket, for the time being I was wondering if there is any other way to nicely subscript in math mode in LaTeX.

Comment: You could also try escaping the Markdown character with a backslash: `$3\_{x}`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`_` is equal to `\sb`. Just use `$3\sb{x}$`.

Comment: And `^` is equal to `\sp`.

Comment: Or you can define your own with `\let\whatever_` or `\def\whatever{_}` (in this last case, it's not equal, but just expands to `_`).

Comment: Yeah for some reason `\sb` had issues as well, so I ended up just writing a little macro in the script for the template that expands to `_`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What problems did `\sb` give you?

Comment: Undefined control sequence, I suppose it is because I'm using a MathJax script?

Answer (score 2):

On the platform I'm using, `\sb` was undefined, perhaps because it's using MathJax like @miradulo said. At least on my platform though, I was able to "escape" the underscore.

**Before:**

```
$$|A\rangle=\alpha_u|u\rangle+\alpha_d|d\rangle$$
```

[image]

**After:**

```
$$|A\rangle=\alpha\_u|u\rangle+\alpha\_d|d\rangle$$
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this answer is wrong. It might work on your "platform" (whatever that may be) but not in TeX.

Comment: I agree but when I searched my problem on Google, this was the first hit. So I thought it might help others.

Comment: @campa: This site is for TeX, LaTeX *and friends* — i.e. closely related systems. MathJax (which this looks like) is generally considered borderline, as described in its tag description; questions about its LaTeX-like input language are usually accepted as on-topic (as opposed to eg installation issues for it, which are not).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I disagree. A MathJax answer might be borderline on topic if at least it works the same way in TeX. However, this answer will _fail_ in TeX systems, and as such I consider it off-topic. Please note that I haven't downvoted or flagged the answer; but I've stated my point of view (maybe too harshly, and I apologize for that) and I stand by it.

Comment: MathJax and Katex clearly state that they don't support full LaTeX and would try to provide only most used commands.